# Customising the a GridViewTextBoxColumn to allow me to have a button at Cell Edit Time

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have created a Custom GridViewTextBoxColumn to handle the following:

1) Display as a Normal TextboxColumn when not in EditMode (problem area)
1) In Edit Mode, I add AutoComplete to the Cell to prompt the user for a list of items
2) To click an ellipse button I have placed to the left of the textbox to browse (Open's a Form with a Grid of Items with more columns)

I have added all no problem and I can dynamically add the AutoComplte Source in the BeginEdit even on the cell (Or I can add it in the CreateChildElements merthod in the AutoCompleteTextBoxCellElement)

So what happens is the following:

My class is this:

```
public class AutoCompleteTextBoxCell : GridDataCellElement      
{
    public AutoCompleteTextBoxCell(GridViewColumn column, GridRowElement row)
        : base(column, row)
    {

    }
}
```

Then I add this method to add the element, textbox

```
protected override void CreateChildElements()
    {
        txtStockCode = new RadTextBoxElement();
        this.Children.Add(txtStockCode);
        LoadData("Code"); //Adding Auto Complete in this event
    }
```

I also add this so that I can arrange the elements in the cell.

```
protected override SizeF ArrangeOverride(SizeF finalSize)
    {
        RectangleF rect = GetClientRectangle(finalSize);
        RectangleF rectEdit = new RectangleF(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width - (32 + 1), rect.Height);
        RectangleF rectButton = new RectangleF(rectEdit.Right + 1, rectEdit.Y, 32, rect.Height);
        if (this.Children.Count >= 2)
        {
            this.Children[0].Arrange(rectEdit);
            this.Children[1].Arrange(rectButton);
        }
        else
        {
            rectEdit = new RectangleF(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
            this.Children[0].Arrange(rectEdit);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }
```

Then Back on the Grid, I do the following:

```
enter code here
```

private void grdMain_CellBeginEdit(object sender, GridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.Name == "colItem")
            {

```
            RadButtonElement btnMore = new RadButtonElement();
            btnMore.Text = "...";
            btnMore.Click += new EventHandler(btnMore_Click);
            grdMain.CurrentCell.Children.Add(btnMore);
        }
    }
```

This adds my button so that I can launch the browse form at the Edit Mode of the cell.

The in the EndEdit Event, I remove the button.

```
private void grdMain_CellEndEdit(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Name == "colStock")
        {
            if (this.grdMain.CurrentCell.Children.Count <= 2) //This might be 1 or 2
            {
                if (grdMain.CurrentCell.Children.Count == 2) // If its two, I need to remove the button
                {
                    if (grdMain.CurrentCell.Children[1] is RadButtonElement)
                    {
                        this.grdMain.CurrentCell.Children.RemoveAt(1);
                    }
                    //If one, I do nothing for the moment. -- I think.
                }
            }  
        }
    }
```

All is fine accept for one problem.

When the cell is added I assume it will go back to behave just like a normal textbox column (due to my inheritance), but its not, the text is hidden - well I cant see it.

When I click the cell to enter edit mode, the text i entered is there.

I do think this is a problem with what I am trying to achieve, I think its an issue with the chain of events.

Can any one tell me why the text is not showing when the cell is not in edit mode?

Regards
John